# Change value of a single cell in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, edit, powerquery, m

I am trying to change the value of a single cell in power bi. When I go into the "data" view then right click and then go to "edit query" I have the option for "replace values". This works like a find and replace, the issue I am having is that if there are multiple cells with the same values they will all get changed. How can I just edit a single cell??

Comment: Could you change the value in the original data source?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not as easy as just editing the cell. If you do not have an index/id column in your table then add one (there is a button on the toolbar to do this).

Then create a new custom column in M (PowerQuery / the data prep language of PowerBI), along the lines of:

```
NewColumn = IF ([Index] = "Index Number" and [YourColumn] = "<your value>") 
               THEN "The new text" 
               ELSE [YourOriginalColumn]
```

Rename or remove the original column and rename NewColumn to the original column name.